SageMath and Magma give different results on calculation intended to get same result
I am trying to evaluate a basis of a Riemann-Roch space of a function field's divisor on places in that function field in Magma and SageMath.
I ran the following code in Magma:
k := 8; 
Fq := GF(2^k); 
F := FunctionField(Fq); 
places := Places(F, 1); 
G := &+[places[i]: i in [2..k]]; 
B := Basis(G); 
places := [places[i]: i in [k+1..2*k]]; 
M := Matrix([[Evaluate(f, P): P in places]: f in B]); 
M;

and got
[ Fq.1^10 Fq.1^177  Fq.1^26 Fq.1^128 Fq.1^206  Fq.1^98 Fq.1^161 Fq.1^173]
[ Fq.1^17 Fq.1^185  Fq.1^35 Fq.1^138 Fq.1^217 Fq.1^110 Fq.1^174 Fq.1^187]
[ Fq.1^24 Fq.1^193  Fq.1^44 Fq.1^148 Fq.1^228 Fq.1^122 Fq.1^187 Fq.1^201]
[ Fq.1^31 Fq.1^201  Fq.1^53 Fq.1^158 Fq.1^239 Fq.1^134 Fq.1^200 Fq.1^215]
[ Fq.1^38 Fq.1^209  Fq.1^62 Fq.1^168 Fq.1^250 Fq.1^146 Fq.1^213 Fq.1^229]
[ Fq.1^45 Fq.1^217  Fq.1^71 Fq.1^178   Fq.1^6 Fq.1^158 Fq.1^226 Fq.1^243]
[ Fq.1^52 Fq.1^225  Fq.1^80 Fq.1^188  Fq.1^17 Fq.1^170 Fq.1^239   Fq.1^2]
[ Fq.1^59 Fq.1^233  Fq.1^89 Fq.1^198  Fq.1^28 Fq.1^182 Fq.1^252  Fq.1^16]

When I ran the following code in SageMath
k = 8
m = 16
Fq = GF(2^k, 'x')
F.<y> = FunctionField(Fq)
places = F.places()
G = sum(places[i] for i in range(1,k))
B = G.basis_function_space()
places = places[k:2*k]
M = matrix([[f.valuation(p) for p in places] for f in B])
print(M)

I got
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] 
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

When I printed out places in Magma I got
[ (1/$.1), ($.1), ($.1 + Fq.1), ($.1 + Fq.1^2), ($.1 + Fq.1^3), ($.1 + Fq.1^4), ($.1 + Fq.1^5), ($.1 + Fq.1^6), ($.1 + Fq.1^7), ($.1 + Fq.1^8), ($.1 + Fq.1^9), ($.1 + Fq.1^10), ($.1 + Fq.1^11), ($.1 + Fq.1^12), ($.1 + Fq.1^13), ($.1 + Fq.1^14), ($.1 + Fq.1^15), ($.1 + Fq.1^16), ($.1 + Fq.1^17), ($.1 + Fq.1^18), ($.1 + Fq.1^19), ($.1 + Fq.1^20), ($.1 + Fq.1^21), ($.1 + Fq.1^22), ($.1 + Fq.1^23), ($.1 + Fq.1^24), ($.1 + Fq.1^25), ($.1 + Fq.1^26), ($.1 + Fq.1^27), ($.1 + Fq.1^28), ($.1 + Fq.1^29), ($.1 + Fq.1^30), ($.1 + Fq.1^31), ($.1 + Fq.1^32), ($.1 + Fq.1^33), ($.1 + Fq.1^34), ($.1 + Fq.1^35), ($.1 + Fq.1^36), ($.1 + Fq.1^37), ($.1 + Fq.1^38), ($.1 + Fq.1^39), ($.1 + Fq.1^40), ($.1 + Fq.1^41), ($.1 + Fq.1^42), ($.1 + Fq.1^43), ($.1 + Fq.1^44), ($.1 + Fq.1^45), ($.1 + Fq.1^46), ($.1 + Fq.1^47), ($.1 + Fq.1^48), ($.1 + Fq.1^49), ($.1 + Fq.1^50), ($.1 + Fq.1^51), ($.1 + Fq.1^52), ($.1 + Fq.1^53), ($.1 + Fq.1^54), ($.1 + Fq.1^55), ($.1 + Fq.1^56), ($.1 + Fq.1^57), ($.1 + Fq.1^58), ($.1 + Fq.1^59), ($.1 + Fq.1^60), ($.1 + Fq.1^61), ($.1 + Fq.1^62), ($.1 + Fq.1^63), ($.1 + Fq.1^64), ($.1 + Fq.1^65), ($.1 + Fq.1^66), ($.1 + Fq.1^67), ($.1 + Fq.1^68), ($.1 + Fq.1^69), ($.1 + Fq.1^70), ($.1 + Fq.1^71), ($.1 + Fq.1^72), ($.1 + Fq.1^73), ($.1 + Fq.1^74), ($.1 + Fq.1^75), ($.1 + Fq.1^76), ($.1 + Fq.1^77), ($.1 + Fq.1^78), ($.1 + Fq.1^79), ($.1 + Fq.1^80), ($.1 + Fq.1^81), ($.1 + Fq.1^82), ($.1 + Fq.1^83), ($.1 + Fq.1^84), ($.1 + Fq.1^85), ($.1 + Fq.1^86), ($.1 + Fq.1^87), ($.1 + Fq.1^88), ($.1 + Fq.1^89), ($.1 + Fq.1^90), ($.1 + Fq.1^91), ($.1 + Fq.1^92), ($.1 + Fq.1^93), ($.1 + Fq.1^94), ($.1 + Fq.1^95), ($.1 + Fq.1^96), ($.1 + Fq.1^97), ($.1 + Fq.1^98), ($.1 + Fq.1^99), ($.1 + Fq.1^100), ($.1 + Fq.1^101), ($.1 + Fq.1^102), ($.1 + Fq.1^103), ($.1 + Fq.1^104), ($.1 + Fq.1^105), ($.1 + Fq.1^106), ($.1 + Fq.1^107), ($.1 + Fq.1^108), ($.1 + Fq.1^109), ($.1 + Fq.1^110), ($.1 + Fq.1^111), ($.1 + Fq.1^112), ($.1 + Fq.1^113), ($.1 + Fq.1^114), ($.1 + Fq.1^115), ($.1 + Fq.1^116), ($.1 + Fq.1^117), ($.1 + Fq.1^118), ($.1 + Fq.1^119), ($.1 + Fq.1^120), ($.1 + Fq.1^121), ($.1 + Fq.1^122), ($.1 + Fq.1^123), ($.1 + Fq.1^124), ($.1 + Fq.1^125), ($.1 + Fq.1^126), ($.1 + Fq.1^127), ($.1 + Fq.1^128), ($.1 + Fq.1^129), ($.1 + Fq.1^130), ($.1 + Fq.1^131), ($.1 + Fq.1^132), ($.1 + Fq.1^133), ($.1 + Fq.1^134), ($.1 + Fq.1^135), ($.1 + Fq.1^136), ($.1 + Fq.1^137), ($.1 + Fq.1^138), ($.1 + Fq.1^139), ($.1 + Fq.1^140), ($.1 + Fq.1^141), ($.1 + Fq.1^142), ($.1 + Fq.1^143), ($.1 + Fq.1^144), ($.1 + Fq.1^145), ($.1 + Fq.1^146), ($.1 + Fq.1^147), ($.1 + Fq.1^148), ($.1 + Fq.1^149), ($.1 + Fq.1^150), ($.1 + Fq.1^151), ($.1 + Fq.1^152), ($.1 + Fq.1^153), ($.1 + Fq.1^154), ($.1 + Fq.1^155), ($.1 + Fq.1^156), ($.1 + Fq.1^157), ($.1 + Fq.1^158), ($.1 + Fq.1^159), ($.1 + Fq.1^160), ($.1 + Fq.1^161), ($.1 + Fq.1^162), ($.1 + Fq.1^163), ($.1 + Fq.1^164), ($.1 + Fq.1^165), ($.1 + Fq.1^166), ($.1 + Fq.1^167), ($.1 + Fq.1^168), ($.1 + Fq.1^169), ($.1 + Fq.1^170), ($.1 + Fq.1^171), ($.1 + Fq.1^172), ($.1 + Fq.1^173), ($.1 + Fq.1^174), ($.1 + Fq.1^175), ($.1 + Fq.1^176), ($.1 + Fq.1^177), ($.1 + Fq.1^178), ($.1 + Fq.1^179), ($.1 + Fq.1^180), ($.1 + Fq.1^181), ($.1 + Fq.1^182), ($.1 + Fq.1^183), ($.1 + Fq.1^184), ($.1 + Fq.1^185), ($.1 + Fq.1^186), ($.1 + Fq.1^187), ($.1 + Fq.1^188), ($.1 + Fq.1^189), ($.1 + Fq.1^190), ($.1 + Fq.1^191), ($.1 + Fq.1^192), ($.1 + Fq.1^193), ($.1 + Fq.1^194), ($.1 + Fq.1^195), ($.1 + Fq.1^196), ($.1 + Fq.1^197), ($.1 + Fq.1^198), ($.1 + Fq.1^199), ($.1 + Fq.1^200), ($.1 + Fq.1^201), ($.1 + Fq.1^202), ($.1 + Fq.1^203), ($.1 + Fq.1^204), ($.1 + Fq.1^205), ($.1 + Fq.1^206), ($.1 + Fq.1^207), ($.1 + Fq.1^208), ($.1 + Fq.1^209), ($.1 + Fq.1^210), ($.1 + Fq.1^211), ($.1 + Fq.1^212), ($.1 + Fq.1^213), ($.1 + Fq.1^214), ($.1 + Fq.1^215), ($.1 + Fq.1^216), ($.1 + Fq.1^217), ($.1 + Fq.1^218), ($.1 + Fq.1^219), ($.1 + Fq.1^220), ($.1 + Fq.1^221), ($.1 + Fq.1^222), ($.1 + Fq.1^223), ($.1 + Fq.1^224), ($.1 + Fq.1^225), ($.1 + Fq.1^226), ($.1 + Fq.1^227), ($.1 + Fq.1^228), ($.1 + Fq.1^229), ($.1 + Fq.1^230), ($.1 + Fq.1^231), ($.1 + Fq.1^232), ($.1 + Fq.1^233), ($.1 + Fq.1^234), ($.1 + Fq.1^235), ($.1 + Fq.1^236), ($.1 + Fq.1^237), ($.1 + Fq.1^238), ($.1 + Fq.1^239), ($.1 + Fq.1^240), ($.1 + Fq.1^241), ($.1 + Fq.1^242), ($.1 + Fq.1^243), ($.1 + Fq.1^244), ($.1 + Fq.1^245), ($.1 + Fq.1^246), ($.1 + Fq.1^247), ($.1 + Fq.1^248), ($.1 + Fq.1^249), ($.1 + Fq.1^250), ($.1 + Fq.1^251), ($.1 + Fq.1^252), ($.1 + Fq.1^253), ($.1 + Fq.1^254), ($.1 + 1) ]

and when I printed out places in SageMath I got
[Place (1/y), Place (y), Place (y + x), Place (y + x^2), Place (y + x^3), Place (y + x^4), Place (y + x^5), Place (y + x^6), Place (y + x^7), Place (y + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^4 + x + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x^3), Place (y + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x + 1), Place (y + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^4 + x^3), Place (y + x^5 + x^4), Place (y + x^6 + x^5), Place (y + x^7 + x^6), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^5 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x^2), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^4 + x^2), Place (y + x^5 + x^3), Place (y + x^6 + x^4), Place (y + x^7 + x^5), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^4 + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^3), Place (y + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^4 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x^2), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^3), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + 1), Place (y + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^5 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^2), Place (y + x^4 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^3), Place (y + x^6 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^5 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^2), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^6 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x), Place (y + x^4 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^3), Place (y + x^7 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^4 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x^3), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^6 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^4 + x), Place (y + x^5 + x^2), Place (y + x^6 + x^3), Place (y + x^7 + x^4), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^4 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^5 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^6 + x^4 + x^3), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^4), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x + 1), Place (y + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1), Place (y + x^5 + x^4 + x^2 + x), Place (y + x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2), Place (y + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^3), Place (y + x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 + 1), Place (y + x^6 + x^2 + x + 1), Place (y + x^7 + x^3 + x^2 + x), Place (y + 1)]

The infinite place, the first 8 finite places, and the last finite place are the same but the others are different. I think the different output might have something to do with this but I'm not sure. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Would it be possible to make a little "room" (or "place" as you like) to the mathematical issue before proceding to the codes ?
